# Add new row with select box, text box and Twitter Bootstrap calendar

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image]

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Have a add button where it will add a row with Author Name (this will be fetched from the database), Percentage level (text box) and Bootstrap Calendar (using Twitter Bootstrap)
2. Have all the values posted to the next page i.e `process.php` where it will get stored in the database.

My current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        new_elem = $("#addr_template").clone().appendTo("#container tbody")
                   .show().attr("id", "addr" + counter);
        counter += 1;
    });
});
```

Now, with the above code (fiddle) I'm able to add multiple row with a button click, I have two problems:

1. The bootstrap calendar is not working in the jQuery AJAX load (button click).
2. All the values are not getting post to the next page.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8PduS/)

Comment: Please include your code in this question. If jsfiddle goes down this question will be unanswerable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Please check it again, and  help me out . thanks for your feedback/comments

Answer (score 2):

I have included datepicker initialization after the row is added once more.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        new_elem = $("#addr_template").clone().appendTo("#container tbody").show().attr("id", "addr" + counter);
        counter += 1;
        $('#datepicker.input-daterange').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PduS/1/)

Comment: @Vaibss_Cool - Wow, my life-saver. Please help me out in posting the values to next page. I need to post all the values to process.php. Don't know where I went wrong with the html tags. Please help me. As you said, jQuery calendar is working fine. Lemme add points to your answer

Comment: @Vaibss_Cool - Yup, the #1 is solved. Please give me a solution for the second also man.. thanks a ton lot. waiting for your answer.

Comment: Noprobs @user3350885.. Glad it helped you ..i am trying to know your second prob.. can u elaborate the prob..?

Comment: thanks again. I mean. Say for example. I have five rows (i have clicked the add button four times). So totally there will be five rows now. right. i need to post all the values to the next page, so that i can store it in db. in other words, i have to take 5x3 (five rows with three fields each) to the next page. i.e process.php

Comment: I have edited my question and added more info for #2. Please help me out.

Comment: I have done something..plz have a look at this link ..http://jsfiddle.net/8PduS/3/ in this i am trying to get the values of the percentage and date.. of all the rows .. add as many columns and press the get value button..

Comment: oh. it means, we can get the values only in javascript and can't be passed to the next page? yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54026/discussion-between-user3350885-and-vaibs-cool).

Answer (score 1):

Update your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/8PduS/2/) - Problem #1

```
$('#datepicker.input-daterange').datepicker({...});
```

The datepicker code should also be implemented after cloning the table row. In your code, the rows dynamically generated never  got bound to the datepicker function.

Comment: the #1 is solved. thanks. Could you help me with the second problem. #2 ?? Please. I need to post all the values to process.php page.. Please/

Comment: thanks again. I mean. Say for example. I have five rows (i have clicked the add button four times). So totally there will be five rows now. right. i need to post all the values to the next page, so that i can store it in db. in other words, i have to take 5x3 (five rows with three fields each) to the next page. i.e process.php

Comment: In my case all the parameters are getting passed, except the parameters from the hidden table row `<tr id='addr_template' style="display:none">`. Please check it. I am not much into php.

Comment: yup, you are right. I'm trying to pass the addr_template values also.. hope someone will help me out for sure.